# How to get original class of a field declared in java class

Tags: java, reflection, field

Here we go, suppose if  i have class Name :

```
class Name {
  String firstName, lastName;
  // getters and setters, etc.
}

and then Name class's object is declared somewhere in other class :

class Other {
  Name name;
  // getter and setters, etc.
}
```

Now if i do something like :

```
Other o = new Other();
Field[] fields = o.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

fields[0] --> is 'name' the Object of 'Name' class
```

but when i say `field[0].getClass()` :

It gives me `java.lang.reflect.Field` class object and not **Name** class object.

How can i get **original** class object from a field like **'name'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fields[i].getType()
```

Please check
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getType()

getType() Returns a Type object that represents the declared type for the field represented by this Field object.

```
field[0].getClass()
```

Will return you the Type object that represents field[0] which is obiviously field[0].

Answer (score 3):

`Field.getType` method returns a Class object that identifies the declared type for the field represented by this Field object.

Answer (score 2):

```
This should help


Other o = new Other();
Class<?> classTemp1 = o.getClass();
Field[] allFields = classTemp1.getDeclaredFields();
```

Now u can query each field for **name ,type** etc

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to ask the field for the value of a specific instance, something like

```
Name name = (Name)fields[0].get(o);
```

Now.  It's pretty dangrous to do a blind cast like this, I'd be probably simply assign it to a `Object` first and then do `instanceof` or maybe use `Field#getName` to determine the name of the field and take action from there...

*nb- I'd make mention of `getType`, but Evgeniy Dorofeev beat me to it and I don't want take away from his answer*

Answer (score 1):

Based on Evgeniy's answer, this line is what you are looking for:

```
String actualClassName = fields[0].getType().getName();
```